# How do I add ads to my game without using xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, admob

I want to add ads to my game however Im not using xml. I know I should learn however, this is my first game and I just want to release it first. This is what I have so far. I also have followed the [Admob tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) up until the part that says to edit main_activity.xml. How should I go about adding the ads now?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.Flag_FULLSCREEN);

    //scale image
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    size = new Point();
    dispay.getSize(size);
    dispX = size.x;
    dispY = size.y;
    bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.bg),dispX,dispY,true);
    bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.losescreen),GamePanel.rescaleX(805),GamePanelrescaleY(1105),true);
    bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.playbutton),GamePanel.rescaleX(242),GamePanelrescaleY(242),true);

    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a replacement to adding the adview in xml:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
// Lookup the layout where you want to place the ad unit
// give the layout an id in the layout xml
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
// Add the adView to the activity's layout
layout.addView(adView);
```

Rest of the code below this as per the tutorial.